# How to search multiple string in column and update cell vales?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search, contains

I have been trying to update the Column values in data frame based on another Column values which contains strings.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

1.   df=pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\bahlrajesh23\\datascience\\Invoice.xlsx')
2.   df1 =( df[df['Vendor'].str.contains('holding')] )
3.   df['cat'] = pd.np.where(df['Vendor'].str.contains('holding'),"Yes",'' )
4.   print(df[0:5])
```

The code up to line 4 above is working well but now I want to add more conditions in line 3 and I amended the line 3 above  like this.

```
df['cat'] = pd.np.where((df['Vendor'].str.contains('holding'),"Yes",''),
                        (df['Vendor'].str.contains('tech'),"tech",''))
```

I am getting following error

```
ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're wanting to return different answers for each condition, using `np.where()` won't work. `map()` would also be difficult.

You can use `apply()` and make the function as complex as you need.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Vendor':['techi', 'tech', 'a', 'hold', 'holding', 'holdingon', 'techno', 'b']})
df

def add_cat(x):
    if 'tech' in x:
        return 'tech'
    if'holding' in x:
        return 'Yes'
    else:
        return ''
        
df['cat'] = df['Vendor'].apply(add_cat)

      Vendor   cat
0      techi  tech
1       tech  tech
2          a
3       hold
4    holding   Yes
5  holdingon   Yes
6     techno  tech
7          b
```

Comment: I wrote like this

Comment: This doesn't work because when I apply this function in my dataframe column , it is giving error "  TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable". 

This means that your solution will only work if everything is Text.

Comment: Then please add a representative example of your data. Or change your floats to text. It’s unclear why you’d be searching for text in a float element.